# AdMob: Missing required XML attribute adUnitID

Tags: android, admob, identifier

I'm new to the ad stuff, and I can't get it working.
I've done what's stated at http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html.

This is my main.xml:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="com.niek.runningapp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
<!-- more stuff-->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="a14da18492dd1f0"
            ads:adSize="BANNER" />
    </TableRow>
<!-- More stuff -->
```

This is my attrs.xml in res/values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
      <attr name="adSize">
          <enum name="BANNER" value="1"/>
          <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2"/>
          <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3"/>
          <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4"/>
      </attr>
      <attr name="adUnitId" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

The following error occurs when I run the app:

> Invalid adSize paramter in XML layout: -1. Defaulting to BANNER
>
> AdView missing required XML attribute adUnitId.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for sharing what was wrong. I was having the same problem and this helped me.

Comment: Niek could you add your Fix as an Answer below and mark as answered, to help others search and find this. Thanks

Comment: Devs, if you are using your project package in xmlns:ads, then you also need to add 'attrs.xml' as explained by James [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5843540/333137).
For newer Admob sdk, attrs.xml is no longer recommended. 
Just use the following namespace:
`xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Anyone who still struggle with it may try `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`.

Answer (score 3):

Per latest SDK , it should be following:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```