# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.google.example' main.xml

Tags: android, admob

When I followed the instructions to add an ad into my app by xml, I got the following errors:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.google.example'  main.xml    /HelloWorld/res/layout  line 12 Android AAPT Problem
Description Resource Path Location Type
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adUnitId' in package 'com.google.example'    main.xml    /HelloWorld/res/layout  line 12 Android AAPT Problem
```

I did edit the `main.xml`, add `attrs.xml` file but the compiler didn't like it.

Comment: Paste the layout and the attrs.xml

Answer (score 300):

Replace `/res/` with `/lib/` in your custom layout nampespace.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

in your case, would be:

```
xmlns:yourApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.yourAppPackege.yourClass"
```

Comment: I had a different problem, but the same solution worked.  Basically I was using a layout file that references the /res file which I changed to /lib per the instructions here and it worked.  Can you provide an explanation of what is going on here?

Comment: xmlns:yourApp="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto";

Comment: Hi, What is yourApp and yourClass in above solution?

Comment: please write one example

Comment: whenever I do that and re build the project It automatically converts the same to previous one and throws the error

Comment: How to do you use it with different package id? for example when you have applicationIdSuffix in build type?

Comment: @Programmer your app id, the package name you'v declared in manifest

Answer (score 74):

I had the same problem. I copied the example code from Google code, and could not compile.

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.example"
```

Finally, I figured it out. The last part of the code "`com.google.example`", is their package name, so you need to replace it with your project package.

For example, my project package is "`com.jms.AdmobExample`", so my `ads` naming space is:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jms.AdmobExample"
```

Check my example, it works fine. You can download the APK to try. I also put my source code here: [Add Google Admob in Android Application](http://android.jmsliu.com/209/add-google-admob-in-android-application.html)

Comment: Devs, if you are using your project package in xmlns:ads, then you also need to add 'attrs.xml' as explained by James in his link.
For newer Admob sdk, attrs.xml is no longer recommended. 
Just use the following namespace:
`xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`

Comment: @vivek.m, thank you for pointing me the correct answer! Instead apk/res one MUST use apk/lib in case of 'apklib' project dependency.

Comment: Thanks, I love internet, specially Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks a lot, after 3 hours of searching and debugging your answer finally popped up and fixed it.

Comment: @vivek.m  thanks that is the answer that worked for me -- with the com.google.ads.

Answer (score 42):

for me, I have to add

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

right after:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

in res/layout/main.xml

Comment: You are the life & sleep saver... Thank you, u saved my sleep :)

Comment: I have an admob question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389729/ads-are-loading-but-not-showing\

Answer (score 27):

You can also use http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto that would take care of it automatically. Use it like this:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: @Niklas: This is not a web page link. This is a URL to be used like this: xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" which automatically resolves the resource URL. See my updated answer above.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but while using a library project. The issue has been solved in r17:
Instead of using the package's namespace:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/hu.droidium.exercises"
```

One has to use a dummy namespace:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

This will fix the problem of the attributes not being accessible from the referencing project.

Answer (score 8):

i download the same custom-demo from [Android.com](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/custom-views/making-interactive.html#makesmooth) and get the same complie problem.

at frist ,i change

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.android.customviews"
```

to

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.example.android.customviews"
```

it work . then i get another solution

```
 xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

it also work, but there are some differencies. The second solution has prefect function . i am finding the reason , may be you can have a hand in. thanks

Comment: "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" add all the attributes defined in your project as well as defined in libraries you referanced in your project. therefore it works for you and its more cleaner approach

Answer (score 3):

As you specify in your `attrs.xml` your adSize attribute belongs to the namespace `com.google.ads.AdView`. Try to change:

```
android:adUnitId="a14bd6d2c63e055"         android:adSize="BANNER"
```

to

```
ads:adUnitId="a14bd6d2c63e055"         ads:adSize="BANNER"
```

and it should work.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales i did add it but still it is not working

Answer (score 3):

I received this error with regards to the largeHeap Attribute, my application did not run under eclipse but under ant it still built and ran normally.

The android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#nspace) states that:

> **attributes:**
>
> `xmlns:android`
>
> Defines the Android namespace. This attribute should always be set to "`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`".

I erased that line in my manifest, saved in eclipse, pasted the line back in and saved again, and it worked. In my case I guess the problem was eclipse, ant and adb not talking to each other correctly and the saving reset something. Interestingly restarting eclipse did not solve this problem (usually with these types of problems restarting eclipse is the first thing you should try, and usually it solves the problem).

Comment: Thx this pls the change of "xmlns:" url saved me :)

Comment: I have an admob question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389729/ads-are-loading-but-not-showing

Answer (score 2):

Make Sure you have included this part in your layout (top below xmlns:android line)

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.example" 
...........blah blah..
```

Also Check whether you have included attrs.xml in the res/values/

Check here for more details.
http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613398/solved-admob-missing-required-xml-attribute-adunitid), I think you need to change the xmlns:ads attribute.  For example, change this:

```xml
<com.google.ads.AdView 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.example"
    ...
    />
```

to this:

```xml
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.your.app.namespace" 
    ... 
    />
```

It fixed it for me.  If you're still getting errors, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I usually embed the xmlns:ads property into the adview properties this way:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
```

so that you dont need to embed into the parent every and each time you copy the adview.

Just copy and paste the adview above and paste it anywhere and it should work

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching answer but couldn't find but finally I could fix this by adding `play-service-ads` dependency let's try this:

*) File -> Project Structure... -> Under the module you can find app and there is a option called dependencies and you can add **com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:x.x.x** dependency to your project

I faced this problem when I try to import Eclipse projects into Android Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was missing a dependency in the app level build.gradle.

The solution was to add the dependency as google outlines below:

Open the app-level build.gradle file for your app, and look for a "dependencies" section.

```
dependencies {
    implementation ...SOME_IMPLEMENTATION
    implementation ...SOME_IMPLEMENTATION
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'//<---ADD THIS LINE
}
```

Add the line above, which instruct Gradle to pull in the latest version of the Mobile Ads SDK and additional related dependencies. Once that's done, save the file and perform a Gradle sync.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, I was using `GoogleAdMobAdsSDK-4.1.0.jar` then I tried with `GoogleAdMobAdsSDK-4.0.4.jar` now it is working fine, It is problem with jar file as per my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on MonoDroid when building a class library with Drawables and Layouts files that have `"android:"` attribute in the xml. I get a similar error as the one in the question.

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'textCursorDrawable' in
>   package 'android'

I found from that "android: " attribute is only available in Android API Level 12+ and I was trying to build for an older version. Updating my project to build against Android 4.0 fixed the issue for me. 
Here is where I found the answer. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/ocxKphM5MWM
Just make sure that you are building against the right API level if you get a similar issue, and ensure that the missing identifier exists in that API level that you are build against.

Answer (score 0):

just change the target sdk right click on project then click on 
property select android and select the latest API

Answer (score 0):

The same error was happening to me in the "activity_banner_xml.xml" file inside res/layout folder. What I did to fix it was replace

```
<com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.AdView
```

with

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

There was no references to my package name. 
Also, be sure you set the adUnitId for `ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">`
The add unit Id is located in your res/Values/Strings folder.

So my final layout file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If yours is a gradle project replace:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

with:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the solution that worked for me for this same error.

I right clicked project > properties > (left panel) Android

Right panel under `Library` I removed the faulty library and added it again.

For me this error occurred after a corrupt workspace eclipse file where I had to import all projects again.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was very similar (produces same problem). After refactoring variable name by "refactor -> rename" option in Android Studio (from "value" to "myValue") i found changes in manifest file, too. Meta-data "value" pool has changed to "myValue".

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:myValue="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

After revert file everything seams to be ok again.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

I hope, it will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Add **xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"**,
This will solve your Issue.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.app.activities.Initializer" >


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-123456789/123456789"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
with 
`xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`

then Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

I added in *android.support.design.widget.NawigationView* this parameter:

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

And problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my cure is to simply enable data binding in my app module's build.gradle.

> android {
>      ...
>      dataBinding.enabled = true
>   }

ref - https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/2-way-data-binding-on-android/

Answer (score -2):

PUT 
`compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'`
IN Gradle Dependencies and put this code in nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/org.mainsoft.navigationdrawer"

    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_material_red"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:border_color="#FF000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```