# Error when Importing jazzylistview sample project

Tags: android, jazzylistview

Hello I'm importing jazzylistview sample project and i get the following error in the layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.twotoasters.jazzylistview
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null"
    app:effect="helix"
    app:only_animate_new_items="false"
    app:only_animate_fling="false"
    app:max_velocity="0" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I get the following error on com.twotoasters.jazzylistview line:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'only_animate_fling' in package 
 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'max_velocity' in package 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'effect' in package 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'only_animate_new_items' in package 
 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample'
```

please help me what should i do?

Comment: Your log clearly says that, you are missing the said attributes. Your sample application must contain custom attributes named effect,only_animate_new_items,only_animate_new_items and only_animate_fling.

Comment: the attributes are passed to the constructor of my class but still gives me the error.

Comment: Solved check this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819369/error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-adsize-in-package-com-googl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample"
here instead of using **/com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample** use your package name.