# No resource identifier found for attribute '...' in package 'com.app....'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-view, android-custom-view

I've imported a project from Eclipse to Android studio. It utilizes a custom view:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

I get errors in the lines below from `activity_ro.xml` file like:

> "Error:(136) No resource identifier found for attribute
> 'pstsTabPaddingLeftRight' in package 'com.app.xxxx'"

```
app:pstsDividerColor="#00000000"
app:pstsIndicatorColor="#FF33B5E6"
app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="14dip"
app:pstsUnderlineColor="#FF33B5E6" />
```

I'm not sure if custom views are different for gradle or maybe I'm doing something wrong. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: change your namespace, try android instead of app

Comment: I just tried that. It hasn't worked  @Apurva

Comment: Are you sure you imported everything?

Comment: Yeah I imported everything

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.google.example' main.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819369/error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-adsize-in-package-com-googl)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I just changed:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.app.chasebank"
```

and it stopped generating the errors, `com.app.chasebank` is the name of the package. It should work according to this  [Stack Overflow : No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.google.example' main.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14299159/3469960)

Comment: It worked for me. Android Studio might have some bug related to "res-auto"

Comment: This one worked. I changed to xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.example.myname.myappname"

Comment: I found I could keep my namespace as "res-auto" when I fixed a reference to Android.Support.Design. I'm on Xamarin though so it might be a different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 35):

You can also use  **lib-auto**

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib-auto"
```

Comment: whenever I do that and re build the project
It automatically converts the same to previous one and throws the error

Comment: try using the package name as in the first answer maybe it will work for you @SagarDevanga

Comment: This does'nt work for me. Studio is suggesting to change it as res-auto and throwing an error

Comment: is lib-auto a valid namespace? try removing the whole apk/lib-auto it works just the same. I don't know much about namespaces but I think if you set something invalid you just make AndroidStudio ignore all attributes

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem and solved it using the below steps:

Add this in your app's build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

Use namespace:

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Then use:

`app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_vector_drawable_here"`

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching answer but couldn't find but finally I could fix this by adding play-service-ads dependency let's try this

*) File -> Project Structure... -> Under the module you can find app and there is a option called dependencies and you can add **com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:x.x.x** dependency to your project

I faced this problem when I try to import eclipse project into android studio

[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spUWj.png)

Answer (score 1):

I solved is by using android:background instead of app:srcCompact.

This is caused by xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto". As people have suggested above, you could use /lib-auto or /lib/your-package  but I got suspicious namespace error when I tried using /lib-auto and unexpected namespace prefix error with /lib/my-package .

Answer (score 1):

this helps for me:

on your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me when a PercentageRelativeLayout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html was used and the build was targeting Android 0 = 26. PercentageRelativeLayout layout is obsolete starting from Android O and obviously sometime was changed in the resource generation. Replacing the layout with a ConstraintLayout or just a RelativeLayout solved it.