# Aliased/blocky VectorDrawables on some phones?

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I can not understand and find no information why on some phones the quality of SVG drawable is compressed

Added via Vector Asset
It was downloaded from https://material.io/icons/

Checked on several models: 
- Huawei (<720p): Compressed 
- MEIZU (1080p): Compressed 
- Xiaomi (720p): Norm 
- LeEco (1080p): Norm

No compressed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS63d.png 
Compressed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6einD.png

Comment: How are you assigning the image to that imageview? There are methods to support vector drawables on older API phones that generate .png files, and these can have scaling artifacts.

Comment: Are you using the Support Library to support VectorDrawables on older phones?  If not, then what is probably happening is that the SVGs are being converted to PNG files when you import them.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936590/why-isnt-my-vector-drawable-scaling-as-expected/34936674