# Scaling causes pixelated vector drawables

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I've got a `ConstraintLayout` which I scale by using `scaleX` and `scaleY`, this works perfectly on most devices but I've noticed that `ImageViews` inside the `ConstraintLayout` looks very pixelated on certain phones (OnePlus running Android 9).

**Samsung Galaxy S10, Android 9 with FHD resolution:**

[image]

**Samsung Galaxy S10, Android 9 with WHQL resolution:**

[image]

The `ImageView` uses a vector drawable and we've set the following:

- `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)`
- `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

However the image is still pixelated on certain phones (OnePlus)

Any ideas why?

**Edit**

This is the drawable:

```
<vector
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="52"
    android:viewportWidth="52"
    android:width="24dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#00394D" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M1.0024,26.342C0.8134,12.559 11.873,1.1907 25.6569,1.0018L26.0037,1C39.5995,1 50.8108,12.0613 50.9971,25.658C51.186,39.441 40.1256,50.8093 26.3417,50.9973L25.994,51C12.399,51 1.1878,39.9387 1.0024,26.342ZM25.7394,7.0155C20.6766,7.0856 15.9386,9.1268 12.3982,12.7657C8.8577,16.4046 6.946,21.1976 7.0152,26.2604C7.1562,36.5854 15.6707,44.9863 25.9957,44.9863L26.2592,44.9845C36.7271,44.8408 45.1271,36.2075 44.9843,25.7396C44.8423,15.4146 36.3279,7.0137 26.0037,7.0137L25.7394,7.0155Z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#009DDB" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M26.3287,12.2772C24.6911,12.2772 23.3593,13.6099 23.3593,15.2476L23.3593,28.2101C23.3593,28.4019 23.3795,28.5973 23.4171,28.791L23.4706,28.9811L23.5135,29.1222L23.5862,29.3456C23.6213,29.4297 23.6642,29.5086 23.7089,29.5857L23.7737,29.7048L23.8579,29.8564C23.97,30.0238 24.0962,30.1771 24.232,30.3129L29.5645,35.6464C30.1253,36.208 30.871,36.5164 31.6648,36.5164C32.4586,36.5164 33.2043,36.208 33.765,35.6464C34.9225,34.4889 34.9225,32.6042 33.765,31.4467L29.2982,26.9807L29.2982,15.2476C29.2982,13.6099 27.9664,12.2772 26.3287,12.2772"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

This is the `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/clock"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clock"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` try making it `wrap_content` and let vector adjust it self, and try changing vector size only

Comment: add same File in drawable-xxxhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't my vector drawable scaling as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936590/why-isnt-my-vector-drawable-scaling-as-expected)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to an ImageView

It might solve your problem

and also make sure your vector is not containing decimal value like this .2 or .4 it should be like 0.2 and 0.4 you can analyse it from code inspector

Any you even can change your vector width and height as you set 24dp because it is by default you can try like this it may help

```
<vector android:height="80dp" android:width="80dp"
```

Something like this

Comment: Tried that, updated the question with the drawable and the imageview. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure let me run it on different devices

Comment: I added one more suggestion it may help

Comment: Setting height and width made no difference

Comment: I am really very sorry maybe it only show perfect in my device

Comment: There are all problem regarding the old version like before lolipop 

and in your case it occur on the latest one it might get solve by the time, so it maybe just because of version

Comment: What android SDK are you building with?

Comment: Also, it seems it has to do with the device resolution. I got the same issue on my S10 when I set it to FHD..

Comment: my current SDK  is 28

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant. I'm doing the scaling using `scaleX` and `scaleY` inside `onCreateViewHolder` of a recycler view adapter.