# No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'learnapp.android.example.com.learnapp'

Tags: android, android-activity

I am getting `Error:(26) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'learnapp.android.example.com.learnapp'`
when I try to run my app.I have just started learning android today.I have added a new activity and dint change anything in any xml files.

This is the exact error:

```
Documents/MyProjects/LearnApp/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_display_message.xml
Error:(26) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'learnapp.android.example.com.learnapp'
```

Here is my activity_display_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="learnapp.android.example.com.learnapp.DisplayMessageActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_display_message" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have already read similar questions and saw that either the line

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

or

```
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

was wrong in their case which is not in my case.

Incase it matters this activity's parent activity is MainActivity.java

Comment: Can you try to set the drawable in you code `fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);`

Answer (score 35):

I just changed

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/my_package_name"
```

I saw the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827602/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-in-package-com-app)

Comment: Don't do this. It changes the layout behaviour. If you try with a ScrollingActivity, it turns a mess

Answer (score 14):

change `app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"` for

```
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
```

Comment: but the real question is WHY is Android Studio using "app:srcCompat"???  I'm getting tired of having to change this.

Comment: Because app:srcCompat was added in AppCompat library 23.2, so if you have 23.1, it just don't exist.

You can use android:src, but app:srcCompat supports vector images, so it's better

Answer (score 12):

Also happens when you have outdated versions of the support libraries.

I updated from:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
```

(those were the newest versions at the moment I wrote this)

and the error is gone.

Comment: This ultimately fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can also try

```
android:src = "@drawable/ic_dialog_email"
```

instead of

```
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
```

I had the same error and this worked for me.

Comment: Not good since we can't use vector drawables in pre-lollipop with `android:src`

Answer (score 2):

Add this `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your app level build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just created a new project. So what fixed it for me was updating my build support tools, then creating a new project from scratch.

To update: Android Studio->Preferences...->Appearance & Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK->Android SDK Build-Tools->Check the box to update

Answer (score 0):

i got the similar issue.

my instructor try update API 22 to API 25, and it's work.
maybe you could try on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Happens if you start updating Android Studio and canceled the update midway
complete the update process and everything should be back to normal

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the srcCompat api as follows.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
      android:id="@+id/dashboard"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      srcCompat="@drawable/dash">
```

[More info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html#attr_android.support.v7.appcompat:srcCompat)