# srcCompat Error with API 22

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I'm getting SrcCompat errors when I sync my project. I  have a relative layout with a number buttons and 4 ImageViews. Here is one of the ImageViews:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.bigal.datacollecter_v1.MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imLogoLL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imRinkL"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imRinkL"/>

.......
```

Here is  my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bigal.datacollecter_v1"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Here is 1 of 4 identical errors from the gradle console output:

```
C:\Users\bigal\AndroidStudioProjects\DataCollecter_V1\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(766) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.example.bigal.datacollecter_v1'
```

I've tried: changing srcCompat to src (I get an unexpected namespace error), change res-auto to namespace, change accompat-v7 version, restart, make project, invalidate cache, clean, etc. as per [No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'learnapp.android.example.com.learnapp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161864/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-srccompat-in-package-learnapp-andr)

I'm trying to target Lollipop and eventually move to API 23. Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'learnapp.android.example.com.learnapp'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161864/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-srccompat-in-package-learnapp-andr)

Comment: I tried each of the suggestions previously from that link- changed srcCompat, changed res-auto, changed appcompatv7 version. Didn't work!

Comment: Did you update `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'` to the latest? I think it's 22.2.1

Comment: 22.2.1 didn't help.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a repo or historial of it in more than two years I've been doing this. I think the closest source would be http://android-developers.googleblog.com

Comment: I don't understand your last comment

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it working. I created a new project and transferred all files and code over and it worked properly.........