# Incompatible attribute for srcCompact Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-button

When I build my Android Studio, this error comes up

```
error: '#dad8d8' is incompatible with attribute android.com.eventus:srcCompat (attr) reference [weak].
```

The error came from my button, 
and I can't proceed to another line or download anything from my palette because of this error. So how can I resolve this problem?

I have tried this links below:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645148/cant-use-srccompat-for-imageviews-in-android/35645353)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827602/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-in-package-com-app)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161864/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-srccompat-in-package-learnapp-andr)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

Change the app:SrcCompat="color" to android:background="color"