# Error:(27) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient'

Tags: android, xml, resources, android-relativelayout, android-cardview

[image]
 I added an `ImageButton` to my `CardView`, and when I add `app:srcComapat` to my `ImageButton`.  I'm getting an error like below:

> Error:(27) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in
>   package 'com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient'

here is my **content_main.xml** layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        android:background="#f6f6f6"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/daily"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:src="@drawable/daily" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove `xmlns:app2` line in `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `RelativeLayout` property

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient"
```

**Edit :**

add this

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient"
```

For  more detail visit this : [No resource identifier found for attribute ' ' in package 'com.app....'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827602/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-in-package-com-app)

**Complete Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
        android:background="#ffffff">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        android:background="#f6f6f6"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/daily"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:src="@drawable/daily" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient">

Comment: this is my package name , can edit and give me the correct value @lroman

Comment: @Jaison_Joseph try to `clean` and `rebuild` project.

Comment: @Jaison_Joseph glad to help you.

Comment: Though this solve op question, but this is not a recommended one. Instead use `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" `.  As it is said: "Added support for custom views with custom attributes in libraries. Layouts using custom attributes must use the namespace URI http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto instead of the URI that includes the app package name. This URI is replaced with the app specific one at build time." in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9656#c71

Answer (score 2):

what you are getting it seems like it's just a lint error that can be ignored.

you can use:

> tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"

in your `RelativeLayout` to avoid seeing this error temporarily.

Because `srcCompat` attribute is actually defined within **AppCompat** library, so remember to add **AppCompat** library to your project.

---

**UPDATE**
For another reader how landing in this thread.

**Do not** use app's namespace using project name like:

> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yourproject.name"

Instead use:

> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" .

As it is said in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9656#c71:

> "Added support for custom views with custom attributes in libraries. Layouts using custom attributes **must** use the namespace URI *schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto* **instead of** the URI that includes the app package name. This URI is replaced with the app specific one at build time."

Read more at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9656

Comment: where i can idd AppCompat library

Comment: Add to your app build.gradle `dependencies` the following code:

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1