# Library builds as a submodule, fails as an aar

Tags: android, aar

Made a library, added to my project as a gradle module. Now I decided to switch to maven, so I built my library as an aar, removed it from settings.gradle and changed the compile statement. Now when I build my project I get

```
 Position 22 : No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardBackgroundColor' in package 'my.package'
```

It's an atribute used within the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827602/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-in-package-com-app). Specifically used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31315643/1560102) answer. Right now I'm just happy the project builds, I'll look into the other answers if I get any problems.