# Error:(44) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'package name'

Tags: android

When I open my project, appear follow error: 
 **Error:(44) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'br.com.douglasprogtg.appcond'**,
and my R of my layout, can't find layouts and my all classes they get error.

[image: Message error]
[image: R in classes]

Comment: try to include the namespace of your app to the declaration of the `app` namespace, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28829264/2549828

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource identifier found for attribute ' ' in package 'com.app....'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827602/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-in-package-com-app)