# When I'm Recompiling The apk This Error Shows in apktool windows 10 pro

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This Is Error

C:\Apktool>apktool b abc
I: Using Apktool 2.4.0
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes2 folder into classes2.dex...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
W: C:\Apktool\abc\res\layout-v26\abc_screen_toolbar.xml:5: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'keyboardNavigationCluster' in package 'android'
W:
W: C:\Apktool\abc\res\menu-v22\navigation.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconTint' in package 'android'
W:
W: C:\Apktool\abc\res\menu-v22\navigation.xml:5: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconTint' in package 'android'
W:
W: C:\Apktool\abc\res\menu-v22\navigation.xml:6: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconTint' in package 'android'
W:
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_9214118989992870300.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 19, --target-sdk-version, 27, --version-code, 17, --version-name, 1.0, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL7494347698208578625.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, META-INF/android.arch.core_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_livedata-core.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_viewmodel.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_animated-vector-drawable.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_appcompat-v7.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_cardview-v7.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_customtabs.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_design.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_exifinterface.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_recyclerview-v7.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-compat.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-ui.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-utils.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-fragment.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-media-compat.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-v4.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-vector-drawable.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_transition.version, -0, png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/com_facebook_tooltip_black_background.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/com_facebook_tooltip_blue_background.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/sheet_shadow.9.png, -0, jpg, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Apktool\abc\res, -M, C:\Apktool\abc\AndroidManifest.xml]
W: C:\Apktool\abc\res\menu-v22\navigation.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconTint' in package 'android'
W:
W: C:\Apktool\abc\res\menu-v22\navigation.xml:8: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconTint' in package 'android'

---

Please Help !!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider providing a little more context to your issue. (e.g. are you importing a new project, did you make a change to the project that caused this error). Also try to simplify your post, the last few lines of the text you posted are all that were necessary for this question.

First thing to do is copy/paste the error listed at the end into the browser to see what you can find.

Your error was

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconTint' in package 'android'

Here is the first thing I pulled up.
[No resource identifier found for attribute ' ' in package 'com.app....'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827602/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-in-package-com-app)

Good luck!