# No resource identifier found for attribute

Tags: android

I am trying to learn a bit of material design and have run into an error putting together my app that I have never seen before and cant figure out how to fix.

**The Error**

```
/Users/Rory/Downloads/MaterialDesign/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml
Error:(89) No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiRotateGestures' in package 'info.androidhive.materialdesign'
Error:(89) No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiScrollGestures' in package 'info.androidhive.materialdesign'
Error:(89) No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiTiltGestures' in package 'info.androidhive.materialdesign'
Error:(89) No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiZoomControls' in package 'info.androidhive.materialdesign'
Error:(89) No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiZoomGestures' in package 'info.androidhive.materialdesign'
```

I have tried the solutions show here [error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.google.example' main.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819369/error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-adsize-in-package-com-googl) but that hasnt solved the error. Any help will be great, thanks

**This is my activity_detail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:io="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.FriendsFragment"

    android:id="@+id/content"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photo"
                android:transitionName="photo_hero"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:tint="@color/photo_tint"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"

                android:contentDescription="@string/photo_description" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/floating_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/floating_button_size"

                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

                android:alpha="0.0"

                android:background="@drawable/info_background"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info"

                android:elevation="@dimen/button_elevation"
                android:stateListAnimator="@anim/button_raise"

                android:onClick="showInformation"

                android:contentDescription="@string/info_button_description" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/star"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/floating_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/floating_button_size"

                android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

                android:alpha="0.0"

                android:background="@drawable/info_background"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_star"

                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:stateListAnimator="@anim/button_raise"

                android:onClick="showStar"

                android:contentDescription="@string/star_button_description" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/information_container"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:visibility="invisible">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
                    map:uiRotateGestures="false"
                    map:uiScrollGestures="false"
                    map:uiTiltGestures="false"
                    map:uiZoomControls="false"
                    map:uiZoomGestures="false" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <com.example.android.io2014.ui.AnimatedPathView
                android:id="@+id/star_container"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:visibility="invisible"

                io:phase="1.0"
                io:duration="1000"
                io:fillDuration="500"
                io:fillOffset="400"
                io:strokeWidth="6dp"
                io:strokeColor="#ffffffff"
                io:fillColor="#ffffffff"
                io:svgPath="@raw/star" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin="24dp"

            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"

            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you added Google Map library to your project ?

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, a silly mistake I was over looking