# Not able to add dependecy in gradle(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to add this dependency https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button in to my android studio project and I am getting

```
 Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5
```

I am able to add google play services dependency easily without any problems.

Below is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.planner"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
}
```

Solutions tried:- 1.)Gradle is working in online mode not offline.
                  2.)Cleaned and builded/rebuilded the project.

3.) Changed to

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

in my root gradle file

4.) Tools->android->Sync Project with gradle files

Still no luck in making it work.

P.S.:- Not that it effects the questions, I faced the same problem while trying to add parse sdk via gradle, so I added the jar file independently.

Comment: I added `compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'` in my `build.gradle` and it's OK, you may try `Build->Rebuild project`.

Comment: as i have told in the question, i have already cleaned/ rebuilded the project, my old projects are running fine, just the new project is giving this problem

Comment: Stupid question but I need to ask? Is this library really necessary? I think you can do your own flat button like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346727/android-material-design-button-styles

Comment: its not about only "this" library, it can effect me some other time when i would try to add another library

Answer (score 1):

add

`repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}`

include android tag

```
    android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.planner"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Add fbutton-1.0.5.aar file into your lib folder.

```
repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
```

Add aar file into dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'ARFile', ext:'aar')
}
```

Comment: nope, this does not work, it gives Error:(49) No resource identifier found for attribute 'buttonColor' in package 'com.example.planner'
Error:(49) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shadowColor' in package 'com.example.planner'
Error:(49) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shadowEnabled' in package 'com.example.planner'
Error:(49) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shadowHeight' in package 'com.example.planner'
Error:(49) No resource identifier found for attribute 'cornerRadius' in package 'com.example.planner'

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819369/error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-adsize-in-package-com-googl

Answer (score 1):

Did you noticed how looks like `build.gradle` of a `demo` project?
https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/blob/master/demo/build.gradle

> ```
> apply plugin: 'android'
>
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 19
>     buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
>
>     defaultConfig {
>         minSdkVersion 9
>         targetSdkVersion 19
>         versionCode 2
>         versionName "1.1"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             runProguard false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
>         }
>     } }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
>     compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.4'
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) //    compile project(':library')
>     compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
>  }
> ```

Check if you're not missing something in your Gradle file or you put something wrong

EDIT: I've put whole your build.gradle file into my new project and it's work fine.

If rebuilding not help, create a new clean project and put this build.gradle. Tell me is it works with new project.

EDIT2:

In your project you have two `build.gradle` change the second one to

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: evrything seems fine, your link is invalid

Comment: nope, sorry it still does not works, i think i have some problem in gradle rather than project, i tried to make a new project, I still get the same problem

Comment: yes, it may be a gradle issue. please check your second `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Invalidate cache and restart your android studio. Then sync gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned the project and used "demo" module to test the lib. The lib that you needed was downloaded successfully and this is expected, because it exists in the [maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.hoang8f/fbutton/1.0.2)

The only point I noticed - probably you may have problems with gradle, because there's **runProguard** command, that is not used in gradle no more.
So you may just delete it or change to minifyEnabled false.

After doing this, demo project assembles successfully