# Android error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.google.example'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, admob

i have an error in adding admob in Xamarin Visual Studio 
i find answers in stackoverflow but i cant understand how to do this
[error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.google.example' main.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819369/error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-adsize-in-package-com-googl)
for example this answer :
Replace `/res/` with `/lib/` in your custom layout nampespace.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in your case, would be:

xmlns:yourApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.yourAppPackege.yourClass"
```

I hope it helps.

i cant understand how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Went over the link you posted and I believe these are the steps you should do:

1. Locate the xml file where you put your ad in.
2. Find a tag like this:

> xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/**com.google.example**"

3. Change **com.google.example** to your project package name. so for example if your package name is **com.IR.Ad** then change that tag to:

> xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/**com.IR.AD**"

And for the specific answer that you referenced here:

Change

> xmlns:**android**="http://schemas.android.com/apk/**res**/**android**

To

> xmlns:**app**="http://schemas.android.com/apk/**lib**/**com.yourAppPackege.yourClass**"

where yourAppPackage should be your project package name and yourClass should be the class where you are implementing the ad

Comment: Bro this is a project in githup can u download it and resolve the probleme and upload project egain to understand ?
https://github.com/IhabZaidi/XamarinAdmob