# adding attrs.xml for admob in Xamarin visual Studio

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android

I have an error in adding Admob in Xamarin visual Studio
the error is : `No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.google.example'`
[error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.google.example' main.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819369/error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-adsize-in-package-com-googl)

but I find someone sais that : you must add attrs.xml to solute the problem 
How to do this ? any idea to solute my problem with admob ?

Comment: Some xml files have namspaces which contains xsd data (schema) for validating the xml.  Each xml type file have different format and different schema.  A schema is not required for xml. Are you using the same xml as the posting?

Comment: yes im use the same for admob

Comment: You can check if you xml has error in VS.  From Project menu : Add new item : XML file.  Then paste you xml into window.  Errors will show up in the Error List like any compiler error.  A missing namespace will show up as an error.