# I have problems in Error: (10) No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' and 'adUnitId' in package

Tags: java, android

excuse me, I have problems in Error:

> (10) No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package

and

> Error: (10) No resource identifier found for attribute 'adUnitId' in package

Please help. Thank you in advance
[image]

Comment: Your issue looks similar to the question described in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819369/error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-adsize-in-package-com-googl).

Comment: please try to do a quick search on google before you post a question here. you may find it much faster that waiting somebody to answer your question here.

Answer (score 0):

add your root layout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

and your adview

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```