# Adsize and adUnitID Error?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, admob

I have a problem in my Android app. The errors are:

> \res\layout\main.xml:37: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adUnitId' in package 'com.sherdle.base'
>
> \res\layout\main.xml:37: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.sherdle.base'

Why is this happening?

#### Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layoutholder"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/theme"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- splash  -->

<ImageView 
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/imageLoading1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:src="@drawable/vert_loading"
    />

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
         

<!-- advertisements-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adViewH"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxx"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"/>
    
</LinearLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webkit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adViewH"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressbar"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/myprogressbar"
    android:secondaryProgress="0" />

<!-- Include the slide down view. -->
<include layout="@layout/slide_down_view"
   android:id="@+id/slide_down_view_include"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:visibility="gone"
   android:layout_height="20dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And also my Eclipse shows a cross sign in *mainactivity.java* in this part:

```
    // admob

    if (!(getResources().getString(R.string.publisher_id).equals(""))) {
    // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    } else {
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ali, have you tried solutions provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819369/error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-adsize-in-package-com-googl ?

Comment: it didnt solve for me