# no resource identifier found for attribute 'launchmode' in package android

Tags: java, android, layout

This is my AndroidManifiest.xml File
Their is 2 error
no resource identifier found for attribute 'launchmode' in package android
no resource identifier found for attribute 'stateNotNeeded' in package android

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="a52.puri.fbkunal.com.launcher">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:
        >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.google.example' main.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819369/error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-adsize-in-package-com-googl)

Comment: Why the last attribute of your `application` tab half eaten? (`android:`)

Answer (score 1):

Assign a `launchMode` into Activity not in application tag.
Basically we could assign a `launchMode` directly as an attribute of `<activity>` tag inside AndroidManifest.xml file list this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SingleTaskActivity"
    android:label="singleTask launchMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning unknown property for `application` tag, `launchMode` in android is for Activities. Activities launch and visible to user but Application launch only once when you start your App. You can say Application is a start point in Android App.