# AdView missing requied xml attribute adSize

Tags: android

I attempted to display adds using code below.
I got the error "**AdView  missing requied xml attribute adSize**".

What is the problem?

main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jms.AdmobExample"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <com.google.ads.AdView     
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="a14f1d807e488dd" />
</LinearLayout>
```

attr.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>
     <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
     <attr name="adSize">
     <enum name="BANNER" value="1"/>
     <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2"/>
     <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3"/>
     <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4"/>
  </attr>
  <attr name="adUnitId" format="string"/>
 </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jms.AdmobExample"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jms.AdmobExample"
        android:id="@+id/add_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        ns:adSize="BANNER"
        ns:adUnitId="a14f1d807e488dd" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

 </Linearlayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it work with Google Play services use:

xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

in your XML file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your adsize attribute is not recognized.

I would say, either your namespace attribute is the problem (add it), either you should check if you called attr.xml "attrs.xml", as it is supposed  to be.

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613398/admob-missing-required-xml-attribute-adunitid) says attrs.xml is not necessary with newer versions of AdMob.

Comment: i already add adsize attribute.what ur saying rolldnums am not getting

Comment: Then you may need to add the namespace in the <AdView> : xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jms.AdmobExample" . Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613398/admob-missing-required-xml-attribute-adunitid since the error seem to happen in the same conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this in the xml file:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```